# How to make the connection more stable between Android and multiple BLE?

Tags: android

I am implement the connection between **`Android`** and **`BLE`**? like **`Anti-lost`** or **`finder`** , After android phone has connected to the BLE device , phone read the RSSI of BLE device every second.

If the **`RSSI of BLE device`** is lower than **`RSSI threshold`** , it deem **`Out of Range`**. For example: **Threshold is -70** , and the **current RSSI of device is -80**.

When app is deem **`Out of Range`**. it send the message to the BLE every 5 second. But it always disconnect after few times. I uses the following code to send the message to the BLE device.

```
BluetoothGattService HelloService = Gatt.getService(HELLO_SERVICE_UUID);

if(HelloService == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "HelloService not found!");
    return;
}

//If the Service is not null , try to get the characteristic.
BluetoothGattCharacteristic Characteristic = HelloService.getCharacteristic(UUID_HELLO_CHARACTERISTIC);

if(Characteristic == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Characteristic not found!");
    return;
}       

Gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(Characteristic, true);

Characteristic.setValue(text, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
Gatt.writeCharacteristic(Characteristic);
Log.d(TAG, "StepCount Characteristic End!");
```

The above code is correct , the BLE can receive the message. But the BLE device will disconnect after few second. It seems do more than one thing in a short time is burden to BLE device.

**The question is: How to make the connection more stable between Android and BLE ?.**

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use notifications if you can avoid it. Based on personal experience with some phones in some environments notifications can stop working and appear to cause general instability. Try to do periodic reads instead.
- Only do a read or write once you have received a callback to `BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicWrite()` or `BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicRead()` for the previous read or write.
- More generally, never do two things at once, whether that be scanning, connecting, reading, writing, whatever. You should serialize all operations using a job queue, only popping from that queue when the previous job completes (or fails).
- In almost-out-of-range scenarios like you're talking about, operations can take a long time to complete, longer than 5 seconds sometimes. So doing another operation in 5 seconds or less you're effectively "stomping" the previous operation. *However*, operations can also never return with a callback in these cases, so you do have to implement a timeout. I use 10 seconds. Beyond that, the operation failed.